# VS2010 C++ Win32 API intellisense

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, winapi

Is where any extension, for visual studio, to support intellisense for c++: 
win32api,mfc,atl whatever. Or its supported, and only i can not see it?
Or any workaround or other IDE?

For example:

```
int main(){
    Set
}
```

And here i want to see all available winapi functions, which starts from "Set". Is it possible?

Comment: vs2010 does have intellisense, you may need to go into your options and turn it on.

Comment: i know, but it doesnt show winapi functions, at least i dont see them

Comment: Have you `#include`d the headers that declare the functions you expect to see?

Comment: Next version of VS will do this automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following snippet:

```
#include <Windows.h>
int main ()
{
    ::Set
}
```

I get all completions for Win32 API functions starting with `Set`.  If you don't like having all those references to the global namespace, you can hit Control-Space to force intellisense to show completions.

Answer (score 1):

That type of C++ intellisense only appears after you hit ctrl+space.

The commercial extension [Visual Assist X](http://www.wholetomato.com/) gives an experience that may be more what you are looking for (note that it is not supported in express editions of Visual Studio).